# json_decode returns NULL on string that has passed through encryption

Tags: php, security, encryption, json

I am trying to secure information on my database and the standard type of data is JSON and I just wrote some simple `mcrypt` functions that encrypt and decrypt any text, here they are:

```
function encrypt($key, $data){
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, $key, $data, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
    return base64_encode($encrypted_data);
}

function decrypt($key, $encryptedData){
    $decrypt = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, $key, base64_decode($encryptedData), MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
    return $decrypt;
}
```

I have a valid JSON string and I've tested the `json_decode` without passing through encryption, and it works. But when I encrypt then decrypt it *then* try to `json_decode` it only returns `NULL`.

Right now I'm just debugging it in a simple script here it is:

```
include("coreFunctions.php");

$arr = '{"number":"4646464646","type":"home"}';

$key = "ladida";
$locked = encrypt($key, $arr);

var_dump($locked);
var_dump(json_decode(decrypt($key, $locked), true));
```

I *have* verified the output of `decrypt` is a the **SAME** as it went in.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

**UPDATE**
I've discovered the `strlen()` before and after is different. So how can I either make sure that it stays the same throughout the encryption process or fix it after it's done?

Comment: If the output of `decrypt` is the same, then this wouldn't be happening.  Check the string lengths... the decryption output might be padded with ASCII null characters.

Comment: Show us a `bin2hex()` dump of the decoded string.

Comment: These encryption functions are garbage.  Where is your random iv?

Comment: `bin2hex` reads: `7b226e756d626572223a2237383635333033303539222c2274797065223a22686f6d65227d0000000000000000000000`

Comment: @Rook i would actually like to learn what `random iv` is, do you have some literature on the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> bin2hex reads:
>   033303539222c2274797065223a22686f6d65227d00000000000000000000

That means you have trailing NUL bytes in the decrypted string. This happens because the `mcrybt_cbc` operates block-wise. It'll fill up input and output to multiples of 16 (or 24) bytes to do so. (The output might sometimes even contain garbage; hencewhy a length field often occampanies most encryption schemes / container formats.)

In your ase you can get away with applying [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim) after the decryption. Or more exactly:

```
 json_decode(rtrim(decrypt($key, $locked), "\0"), true);
```