# encode an array with mcrypt_encrypt() fast method?

Tags: php, arrays, decode, encode

I want to encode a numeric array.
After the encode I want to send the data to another server.

```
$query = "***";
$arr = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_N);
print_r($arr);
```

result of print_r:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => i64lo2
        [2] => Alex
        [3] => ***
        [4] => 213
        [5] => 8
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 1
        [8] => 0
        [9] => 0
        [10] => 1
        [11] => 2015-07-24 12:17:15
        [12] => 2015-07-24 12:17:15
        [13] => ***@***.de
        [14] => 85
        [15] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 2tvplb
        [2] => Peter
        [3] => ***
        [4] => 213
        [5] => 8
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 1
        [8] => 0
        [9] => 0
        [10] => 1
        [11] => 2015-07-24 12:18:51
        [12] => 2015-07-24 12:18:51
        [13] => ***@***.de
        [14] => 85
        [15] => 2
    )
```

my method to encode:

```
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB); 
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);   

   for($i = 0; $i <= count($arr); ++$i){
       for($z = 0; $z <= count($arr[$i]); ++$z){
            echo mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "passwort", $arr[$i][$z], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);   
$z++;


       }
       $i++;        
    }
```

But this is so slowly... Have someone a better idea to encode an array?
I've to decode the code after the encode.

Comment: JSON encode the array and it will be a single string. Then, mcrypt it. On the other end, decrypt it and JSON decode. You will get the array back.

Comment: var_dump(json_decode($json_decode)); The var_dump return NULL ??
json_encode() works fine.. encode the json works fine too.. decode the json encoded code works fine.. It is the same json string.. But decode the json string returns NULL

Comment: This link helps me a lot!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278515/json-decode-returns-null-on-string-that-has-passed-through-encryption